Issue with PageSpeed insights score LCP rendering delay
I have an issue with PageSpeed Insights. For desktop, I get 96+, but on mobile, I get 65-75 on most pages. The reason is always the same: Largest Contentful Paint render delay 78%. while the actual website is fully loaded in 2sec, PageSpeed insights stays in "Idle" state for 7+Sec. I'm using WP with Divi Builder and I tried couple of optimization plugin. After inspecting in Dev Tools, it looks like a timer is fired every 1000ms initiated by Scripts.min.js. Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this issue, or has anyone else experienced similar problems?
Screenshots are provided
the timeline
the timer
I tried using couple optimization plug-ins, and tried removing any extra functions on the website.
